# checkbox pass to input field has conflict in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to add the value of the `checkbox` in the field the is `closest` to it. But I think I missed something. Please see my code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        var output = "";
        $("input:checked").each(function() {
            output += $(this).val() + ",";
        });
        
        $(this).closest('.divs').find(".result").val(output.trim());
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <input type="text" class="result"/><br>

  <input type="checkbox" value="1">1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">3
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="divs">
  <input type="text" class="result"/><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">3
</div>
```

**Update**

I also want to check if the textbox is empty then the value will return back to `empty`. I tried

```
if($(this).closest('.divs').find('.result').val() == ""){
  $(this).closest('.divs').find('.result').val("empty");
}
```

Comment: you can see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myahkg6f/1/) hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the `input type text` attr with `classname` instead of `id`. Target the checkbox value via parent div

**Updated 1**

with `,` unsing `map()` function

**Upadted 2**

Added with empty value

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
        var output  =$(this).closest('.divs').find("input:checked").map(function() {
           return $(this).val();
        }).get();
        var res = output.length ==0 ? 'empty' : output.join(',');
        $(this).closest('.divs').find(".field_results").val(res);
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <input type="text" class="field_results" placeholder="empty"><br>

  <input type="checkbox" value="1">1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">3
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="divs">
  <input type="text" class="field_results" placeholder="empty"/><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">3
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to add extra space at the end, please update the space to `,`

Comment: check my updated answer.i was added with placeholder.it will show the box was empty.

Comment: I want to use `value` attribute not placeholder

Comment: OK .lets check the updated answer. i change function with `change` instead of `click`

Answer (score 3):

First problem is that you have multiple elements with the same Id, Use class for this.

Second, Your using `$("input:checked").each` to get all checked inputs, but use `("input:checked").each` to get all inputs inside the current `div.divs`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    var output = "";
    var length = $(this).parent('.divs').find("input:checked").length;
    $(this).parent('.divs').find("input:checked").each(function(index) {
      output += $(this).val() + (index !== (length - 1) ? "," : "");
    });

    $(this).parent('.divs').find(".field_results").val(output.trim());

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <input type="text" class="field_results" /><br>

  <input type="checkbox" value="1">1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">3
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="divs">
  <input type="text" class="field_results" /><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">3
</div>
```

Comment: @Jonjie Updated

Comment: It's working, `parent()` is not working for me. but it works based on your exmple

Comment: Parent should work if your html is like mine, else use `.closest()`